# Nginx best way for Multiple server_names redirect non www. to www

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting, return

My config :

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

##locations and fastcgi proxy stuff etc down here
}
```

The way I see everyone else doing a 301 redirect (return) is they create a new server block and put the domain host in there like this

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name domain.com;
return 301 $scheme://www.domain.com$request_uri;
##This server block contains no locations etc
}
```

How can I do a redirect from non-www. to www. without creating a new server block ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with:

```
if ($host ~* "^(?!www)(.*)$") {
    set $catch_host $1;
    rewrite (.*) http://www.${catch_host}$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: Where add it  ? in server {

    if ($host ~* "^(?!www)(.*)$") { ?